# Make one button enable a different button

Tags: cocoa, button

I have 4 custom radio buttons that change a message when clicked. The message deals with search terms. I have one search button. Does anyone know of a way to make the search button activate a different action to take you to a different page depending on which of the radio buttons is clicked?

Kind of like having one search button hooked up to 4 different actions and enable/disable the actions from the radio buttons.

If any on knows how to do this with just 2 buttons, then I can figure out the logic for 4 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new working code:

//Search Button

```
-(IBAction)showWineriesButton
{
    btnSearchWineries.hidden=FALSE;
    btnSearchGrapes.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchWines.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchReviews.hidden=TRUE;

}

-(IBAction)showGrapesButton
{
    btnSearchWineries.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchGrapes.hidden=FALSE;
    btnSearchWines.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchReviews.hidden=TRUE;

}

-(IBAction)showWinesButton
{
    btnSearchWineries.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchGrapes.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchWines.hidden=FALSE;
    btnSearchReviews.hidden=TRUE;

}

-(IBAction)showReviewsButton
{
    btnSearchWineries.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchGrapes.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchWines.hidden=TRUE;
    btnSearchReviews.hidden=FALSE;

}˚
```